# Catch UserProfileNoUserFoundException exception

Tags: sharepoint-addin, user-profile-service, csom, exception-handling

I have a requirement where I am checking a user account whether it does exist in User Profile Service or not. And if the account doesn't exist then it will create an account. I am using CSOM for this.

It throws an exception "Forbidden" on `clientContext.ExecuteQuery()` when I don't impersonate the identity and the account doesn't exist. By impersonating the identity the account gets created even for those user whose accounts are already existent which I don't prefer. I am using the following code:

```
var loginName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
var peopleManager = new PeopleManager(clientContext);
var properties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(loginName);
clientContext.Load(properties, p => p.PersonalUrl, p => p.UserProfileProperties);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Is there a way where I can catch `UserProfileNoUserFoundException` exception instead of exception "Forbidden"?